# add next pager to image field views

Tags: views, media

I have a view created from a node with images.
All images are in one field, image field content:afbeeldingen (images)

I have created my view 1 image is one page. I get the next link and previous below my image but now i want to link add a next link to my image in my view how can I do this?

[image: views display]
[image: view]

Comment: I want to link the pager id for the next page to my image. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want is an image gallery or slideshow. There are many image gallery modules you can install (ie views slideshow, Flexslider).

Then you need to set the slideshow to have a pager of its own, and in the image field you need to take care of the display multiple part (as it is a multi image field) to display one image at a time.

So you will end up with two pagers. One for the view, and one for the slideshow.

Or if you want you can try the Field Slideshow module. It builds the slideshow from one multi-instance field, so half the work is done for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Field slideshow module, my slideshow gallery works fine, all i want is wen i click on the image itself it goes to the next image. Instead of pushing the next button on the pager at the bottom i want it to go next page when clicking on the image.

Answer (score 0):

How can I add the url generated by the view (pagination) to my image as a link.
I want to add ?page=1, ?page=2 ... (depending on number of pages(variable)